# Android google MlKit issue

Tags: android, google-mlkit

I am using *Android Google MlKit* for pose estimation. But I am getting the following error message:

> W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException: MlKitContext has not been initialized

> W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkState(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.4.0:29)

> W/System.err:     at com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.MlKitContext.getInstance(com.google.mlkit:common@@17.1.1:2)

If anyone has experienced this issue, please feel free to comment on this thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can call [this method](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/mlkit/common/MlKit#initialize(android.content.Context)) to initialize the MlKitContext manually. Note that Under normal circumstances the content provider will automatically initialize ML Kit at application startup. You might have disabled the content provider declared in the manifest.